# PDF to Jpg with ImageMagick really slow

Tags: php, performance, imagemagick

I have a script that transform **PDF to Jpg with ImageMagick**. It work good, but it's slow. A file with **12 pages will take about 1 or 2 minutes** to get the conversion done. If I have a file with 60 pages, the request will take too much time to respond.
Since I am not an expert with ImageMagick, I was wondering, is there a better approach?

**Code**

```
$pdf = new imagick();
$pdf->pingImage("filepath/fileName.ext");
$pagesNbr = $pdf->getNumberImages();

for($x=0; $x<$pagesNbr; $x++) {
    $img = new imagick();
    $img->setResolution(200,200);
    $img->readImage('filePath/fileName.ext['. $x .']');
    $img->setImageColorspace(13);
    $img->setResolution(72,72);
    $img->resampleImage(72,72,imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
    $img->setCompressionQuality(100);
    $img->setImageFormat("jpg");
    $img = $img->flattenImages();
    $img->writeImage('previews/'. $x .'.jpg'); 
    $img->destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert either but I had a few thoughts that I figured I could share.  Its probably obvious but the more commands you can rid of the faster it will go.  Try loading in the image with the imagick construct.  Do you need to setResolution, imageColorspace, compressionQuality, ImageFormat and flattenImages (honestly I don't know but it seems like you might be able skip at least some of them)...can you resample elsewhere?  What if you don't create a new object for each page but just keep reusing the same one?

In my experience I had better performance running imagemagick through the exec command.  To truly get the best performance you will probably have the best luck finding a program that is specifically tailored to this task and running it from shell.  You can also look into compressing/resizing the pdf prior to processing to make any approach run better.

A last thought...if you can't decrease the converting time is how you present it to the user...uploading the file via ajax and processing it in the background might make it ok for the user to wait a while.  Perhaps you could trigger a popup notifying them when it is done or email them so they aren't waiting.

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful but don't bother with GD...its slow as.

Comment: Thank you. Removing options help a little, I also kept the same object instead of creating a new one for each page as you suggested.